# Excel find profit per seller

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lets say I have the following Excel Table:

```
Seller Name | Sale Profit
Bob  | 150
Jack | 350
Dylan| 200
Bob  | 200
Dylan| 150
Dylan| 120
Jack | 440
Bob  | 100
Bob  | 220
```

How can I make a total per seller, ie.

```
Bob | 670
Jack| 790
...
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: copy the first column to another, use remove duplicates on the new column then use SUMIF() to get the sum.

Comment: Explore Pivot Table in Excel

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort the list
2. Use the Subtotal function from the data ribbon where you subtotal at every change in seller name.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

Copy column **A** into column **C** and then use RemoveDuplicates from column **C**.

Then in **D2** enter:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,C2)
```

and copy down:

[image]